# Abrir programa atraves de link

Tags: php, javascript, html

Preciso acessar por telnet dispositivos de redes (switchs e routeadores) que são exibidos numa listagem.

A ideia era que ao clicar em cima do nome do ativo de rede, abrisse o TeraTerm, ou putty para conexão no dispositivo.

Lembrando que o programa ja esta instalado na maquina, seria basicamente um atalho para a execução.

Porem ja tentei com HTML com link e tambem com Javascript e não tive sucesso.

Teria como fazer isto de alguma outra forma?

Comment: Acredito que teria que configurar um handler de protocolo, tal qual o `mailto` para e-mail, ou o `magnet` para arquivos torrent. Mas não sei como fazer.

Comment: se não foi possivel atraves de link, seria possivel atraves de um botão?

Comment: Talvez se for um botão em um applet Java, mas nunca programei um applet, não sei quão grande são as restrições de segurança impostas pelo sandbox. Do contrário, em um botão comum ou em Flash, com certeza não.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um mime type novo no servidor. Quando selecionar o link, o servidor pode mandar as informações de volta pro cliente com o mime type associado ao putty, ou ao programa que quiser.

Uma lista completa de mime type pode ser vista aqui: http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/

Creio que isso pode funcionar.

Comment: consegui fazer baseado sua resposta, e agora esta abrindo o teraterm, porem tive que associar um arquivo TTL ao tera, pois com o exe não consegui. Agoraestou vendo como passar o endereço IP a ser conectado por parametro, mas parte do problema ja esta resolvido.

Comment: Se colocar o endereço IP em algum parâmetro "header" é só ler o parâmetro, se é o que estou entendendo.